# Does not change color selected row in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to load window in Datagrid 5 row selected

My code, but color does not change

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGridService.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5);
                object item = DataGridService.Items[5];
                DataGridService.SelectedItem = item;

                DataGridService.ScrollIntoView(item);
                row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionColorKey" Color="Red"/>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Style.Resources>
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionColorKey}, Path=Color}"/>
          </Style.Resources>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

May be i not correct formulated problem. I need on load window, background row 5 was red color and focus was in 5 row

It does not work

```
 DataGridService.SelectedItem = DataGridService.Items[5];
```

strangely in Winforms this makes easy

How selected first row?

Why is the problem with selected color?

Comment: Make a style for the `DataGridCell`. So each cell can change it's bachgroundcolor if it is selected

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a style but don't do anything in this style. You have to define some `Setter`s to set properties of the styled object.

Something like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: this does not work. If your code, change background color.I need change color selected item, item 5.

Comment: @VladimirKombarov, well, see my edit. You still need a `Setter` but this time in a `Trigger`.

Comment: I use your code, but selected item 5 not change color

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it is necessary to set the focus on Datagrid

```
DataGridService.Focus();
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGridService.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(100);
            object item = DataGridService.Items[100];
            DataGridService.SelectedItem = item;


            DataGridService.ScrollIntoView(item);
            row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```